# git/bb - how to get the commit done by username?

Tags: git, commit, bitbucket

For a school project, my team used bitbucket as our repo. For the final documentation, we basically have to write about who did what. My prof allowed us to just paste our bb commits and give short explanations of what was committed.

Is there an easy way to get the commits of each user? In the repo there are a lot of merge messages from pull requests, how do I exclude those from the list of commits I'll get?

[image]

Comment: External repository provider is **irrelevant** - you work with local repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command-line you can use the [shortlog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shortlog.html) command to get a formatted report of who did what:

```
git shortlog --no-merges
```

Answer (score 1):

You must to **read docs**, in case of Git - read carefully

[Git log man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) contain all needed information

> git-log - Show commit logs

```
Commit Limiting
...
--author=<pattern> 
...
--no-merges

    Do not print commits with more than one parent. This is exactly the same as --max-parents=1.
```